# Adding libraries in /usr to xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, libraries

I'm trying to add static libraries found under /usr to an xcode project. (I'm new to mac dev).

The problem is that this is a hidden directory and so the normal Add to project doesn't work, and although I can Edit Project Settings to add the include directories, there doesn't seem to be any obvious way of adding the actual libs.

Short of copying the libraries around, or unhiding the /usr dirs (which can't be the correct solution) I'm at a loss.

TIA

Answer (score 10):

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> allows you to type in any path e.g. /usr and then browse from there.

or

Find the file in Finder and drag from Finder and drop on the open file dialog

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *goto location* shortcut (in all Cocoa open/save dialogs): ⌘⇧G. You'll be prompted for a unix path, type `/usr` and, voilà!